# Medley in musicals

Tags: terminology

Terminology:  Toward the end of musicals, it is common to play a medley of previous tunes.  Often they are interwoven.  Does this kind of medley have a specific name?

Comment: This is sometimes referred to as a *finale*, but that word does not imply that the song/piece is a medley.

Answer (score 2):

One name that comes to mind is "reprise."

Answer (score 1):

It could be considered an "overture".  In classical music, an overture is used to restate previous or upcoming themes that are part of the overall piece.

Comment: It is true that the overture of musicals usually is a medley of the show's best tunes. But it comes at the beginning, not the end.

Comment: would it then be called an underture?

Comment: maybe Afterture? :)

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  Repeating a previous song is called a *reprise*, but there's no term that I'm aware of for when several reprises run together.

Answer (score 0):

This has become called 'The MegaMix'.  Possibly originating with the re-vamp of 'Joseph and the Dreamcoat'.   It's become a cliche of Musical Theatre to get the audience up and clapping with such a finale sequence.  Then, as they're up, they might as well deliver a standing ovation :-)